# Posted value does not appear first time but appears second time in php

Tags: php

I'm working on quiz project...

I have to select values from 4 dropdown where the value in 2nd and 3rd drop down comes from ajax page.

When I submit my form the posted value should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [cat_id] => 2
    [quest_id] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [submit] => Save
)
```

but it does not show cat_id and quest_id in posted value because the values are coming from ajax div so I get:

```
Array
(
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [submit] => Save
)
```

Please help..

Thanks

Comment: then you need to have hidden fields in current form which will be populated when you select the value from drop downs which are in DIVs

Comment: can you put the HTML/JS code in a fiddle? Maybe the AJAX loaded parts are outside the form tag

Comment: ajax is working ok.. bcoz its returning the values and the posted value is stored somewhere bcoz after submitting form second time it shows the exact array that i want...

Comment: using framework or cms? post html form please.

Answer (score 0):

A div is not submitted by a form. You need to store the values from your ajax drop down in a hidden input. You can use the onchange event from your drop down.

Comment: We dont need to take a seperate div for drop down
just paas your select tag id
and replace it with options in ajax page.